# Did Yisasschar have a choice not to accept his blessing?

Tags: blessing, vayechi

The passuk right after Yaakov blessed Yissaschar "יששכר חמור גרם" ([ויחי פ' מט יד](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.49.14?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0))" which Rashi explains to mean that he'll be strong like a donkey donkey to hold the "עול התורה", states that Yissaschar saw that he will get a blessed land that's great for agriculture, and ויט שכמו לסבול, i.e. he bent his shoulder to lift the עול התורה onto himself.

It's interesting that it seems that this passuk is the only one in birchas Yaakov which Yaakov himself didn't utter, rather that the blessed one (Yissaschar) looked, and made the decision to accept the blessing.

Is this correct? (I quickly scanned some meforshim, but didn't find anything...).

And if it is then there has to be some message here about קבלת עול התורה, is anyone familiar with anything? (any sources etc. would be appreciated!)